# php foreach insert first one a certain class, if only one has different wrap

Tags: php

My images folder has files format like below

```
    <img src='images/AAA_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/AAA_2.jpg'>
    <img src='images/AAA_3.jpg'>
    <img src='images/BBB_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/BBB_2.jpg'>
    <img src='images/BBB_3.jpg'>
    <img src='images/CCC_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/DDD_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/EEE_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/EEE_2.jpg'>
......
```

my function is

```
function filter($contain){


    foreach ($carousel as $image) {

        if(strpos($image, $contain) === 0){
            $op = "<div class='box'><img src='imgs/$image'/></div>";
        }
    }

}
```

getallfiles is to get imgs folder files.

$name has `AAA_`, `BBB_`, `CCC_`, `DDD_`

How do I insert `first` class for each group, the output expecting is like below

```
<div class="box first"> 
    <img src='images/AAA_1.jpg'> 
</div>
<div class="box"> 
    <img src='images/AAA_2.jpg'> 
</div>
<div class="box"> 
    <img src='images/AAA_3.jpg'> 
</div>
<div class="box first"> 
    <img src='images/BBB_1.jpg'> 
</div>
<div class="box"> 
    <img src='images/BBB_2.jpg'> 
</div>
<div class="box"> 
    <img src='images/BBB_3.jpg'> 
</div>
<div class="box first"> 
    <img src='images/CCC_1.jpg'> 
</div>
<div class="box first"> 
    <img src='images/DDD_1.jpg'> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just trying to set this up in an https://eval.in PHP fiddle, but you haven't given enough information to replicate this. Can you provide examples of `$carousel` and `$name` - and presumably you will define `$carousel` as a global variable so it can be used in that function?

Comment: @scrowler Thanks! $carousel is an `array` output likes `Array ( [0] => AAA_1.jpg [1] => AAA_2.jpg [2] => AAA_3.jpg [3] => BBB_1.jpg [4] => BBB_2.jpg [5] => BBB_3.jpg [6] => CCC_1.jpg ........` yes $carouse is a  global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a variable before the loop which will help you determine whether the first for each letter has been set. You output that class the first time, then set that variable to something that will help you know not to output it again.

Using these arrays:

```
$carousel = array(
  'AAA_1.jpg',
  'AAA_2.jpg',
  'AAA_3.jpg',
  'BBB_1.jpg',
  'BBB_2.jpg',
  'BBB_3.jpg',
  'CCC_1.jpg'
);

$names = array('AAA_', 'BBB_', 'CCC_', 'DDD_');
```

... this function:

```
function filter($name){
    global $carousel;
    $found_first = false;
    foreach ($carousel as $image) {
       if(strpos($image, $name) === 0){
           $first = !$found_first ? ' first' : ''; // assign class if it's the first
           $found_first = true; // change the variable after the first loop
           $html = "<div class='box%s'><img src='imgs/%s'/></div>" . PHP_EOL;
           echo sprintf($html, $first, $image); // output formatted string
       }
    }
}
```

... and this loop:

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    filter($name);
}
```

... you get output like this:

```
<div class='box first'><img src='imgs/AAA_1.jpg'/></div>
<div class='box'><img src='imgs/AAA_2.jpg'/></div>
<div class='box'><img src='imgs/AAA_3.jpg'/></div>
<div class='box first'><img src='imgs/BBB_1.jpg'/></div>
<div class='box'><img src='imgs/BBB_2.jpg'/></div>
<div class='box'><img src='imgs/BBB_3.jpg'/></div>
<div class='box first'><img src='imgs/CCC_1.jpg'/></div>
```