# php foreach check if the name contains same string more than once

Tags: php

My images folder has files format like below

```
    <img src='images/AAA_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/AAA_2.jpg'>
    <img src='images/AAA_3.jpg'>
    <img src='images/BBB_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/BBB_2.jpg'>
    <img src='images/BBB_3.jpg'>
    <img src='images/CCC_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/DDD_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/EEE_1.jpg'>
    <img src='images/EEE_2.jpg'>
......
```

my function is

```
foreach ($those as $image) {
  if(strpos($image, $name) === 0){
          echo "<div class='box'><img src='imgs/$image'/></div>";
   }
}
```

`$those` is an Array

```
  Array  ( [0] => AAA_1.jpg [1] => AAA_2.jpg [2] => AAA_3.jpg [3] => BBB_1.jpg [4] => BBB_2.jpg [5] => BBB_3.jpg [6] => CCC_1.jpg ........
```

how do we test if the same format file name has one more ?
   like file name starts AAA has 3,   BBB has 3,  C has 1, D has 1, EEE has 2,

I'd like to achieve is that

```
if ( check if the file name contains same string more than once ) {
      echo "<div class='box'><img src='imgs/$image'/></div>";
   }else{
      echo "<div class='container'><img src='imgs/$image'/></div>";
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assocative array containting quantities
// of duplicated images Array( [AAA] => 3, [BBB] => 3, [CCC] => 1, [DDD] => 1, [EEE] => 2)
$duplicates = Array();

// Prepare $duplicates
foreach ($those as $image) {
   // $base is string `AAA`, `BBB`
   list($base) = explode("_", $image, 2);
   $duplicates[$base] = isset($duplicates[$base]) ? ($duplicates[$base]+1) : 1;
}

// Now go thru your loop
foreach ($those as $image) {
   list($base) = explode("_", $image, 2);
   if ($duplicates[$base] > 1) {
       echo "<div class='box'><img src='imgs/$image'/></div>";
   }else{
       echo "<div class='container'><img src='imgs/$image'/></div>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify [my answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548432/php-foreach-insert-first-one-a-certain-class-if-only-one-has-different-wrap/22548629#22548629) to do this. This is not the most glamorous solution but does the trick.

Loop over the array once, counting the occurences of the specified string, then loop again to output your results:

```
function filter($name){
    global $carousel;
    // create array to store match counts
    $matches = array();
    foreach($carousel as $image) {
        if(!array_key_exists($name, $matches))
            $matches[$name] = 0; // initialize array keys

        if(strpos($image, $name) === 0)
            $matches[$name]++; // add to the count
    }
    // got the counts, do the outputs
    foreach($carousel as $image) {
        $class_name = 'container'; // default (only one match)
        if($matches[$name] > 1) // get number of matches from previous loop
            $class_name = 'box';
        $html = "<div class='%s'><img src='imgs/%s'/></div>" . PHP_EOL;
        echo sprintf($html, $class_name, $image); // output formatted string
    }
}
```

Note: use [`stripos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) for case insensitive string comparison